# First law of thermodynamics (derivation)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

According to the first law of thermodynamics,
$$dQ=dU+dW$$

The derivation of this formula is as follows:

$dW=Fdx$

where $d$x stands for displacement.

$dW=P(Adx)$

as force = pressure x area and $dW= PdV$.

Finally, $dQ= dU+dW$.

What does $dV$ stand for? And how is $(Adx)=dV$.

Please answer my question in the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$dV$ is the incremental volume. If you have a cylinder with a base of area $A$ and with height $dx$, then the volume will be $dV=A.dx$